# Installtion failed a .deb Package

Tags: installation, command-line, package-management, deb

I try to install a .deb package with terminal use

> **sudo dpkg -i *.deb**

but show this error

> dpkg: error processing Pydict.deb (--install):  parsing file
>   '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 8 package 'pydict': 
>   duplicate value for `Architecture' field Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  Pydict.deb

Comment: Hi . What package is it your are trying to install and what version of Ubuntu are you using please. It will make it easier for us to help you :-)

Comment: 'Architecture' error? Seems like you downloaded the .deb for another architecture than your processor. Like you might need an i386 one and you might have downloaded an AMD package. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install random `.deb` files on any Ubuntu installation. Yes, it works a lot of the time, but sometimes you get errors like yours :)

From what I see, `pydict` is a VERY old python/gtk dictionary package, and it appears its structure is somehow not compatible with the current `dpkg`. Please try to see if a newer version exists...

Answer (score 2):

The exact problem is that the .deb file you are trying to install is **corrupt**. Its metadata is broken, at least one of it's fields is duplicated, which makes `dpkg` unable to deal with this file. It may not be a problem with Ubuntu.

On the other hand, do you need the package? It's deprecated. What is the package and what do you need it for? There may be alternatives if we have more information.